# How can I transfer my games from the system memory to my micro SD card?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I recently got a micro-SD card to expand the storage of my Nintendo Switch but I can't seem to find a way to transfer the games I already installed to the card.

First I tried going to settings and then data management, I can see the micro-SD card here but there doesn't seem to be any option to transfer the game data to it.

[image: Data Management]

I couldn't see anything else in the rest of the settings so I tried the options on the game tile and there was nothing there either.

Then I decided to try and download a game I had previously deleted to save space. The download started normally and was stored on the micro-SD without any issues or options to choose where I wanted it. I did have enough space for it to be on system memory if I wanted it to be there so I found it a bit odd that there was no choice.

Based on the above I could just delete the games I have and re-download them onto the mirco-SD but this seems unnecessarily slow. I would also have to take the micro-SD out if I wanted something installed on the system memory.

Is there a way to transfer games between the system memory and the micro-SD card without re-downloading them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [v10.0.0](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22525/%7E/nintendo-switch-system-updates-and-change-history#v1000), it is now possible to move data between the internal system storage and microSD card without having to go through the hoops provided in the previous answer.

To do this, simply go to System Settings. Under the Data Management menu, the option to "Move Data Between System / microSD" card will be available.

> Users can now transfer downloadable software, update data, and DLC from the system memory to an SD card (and vice versa).
>
> Note that save data and some update data cannot be transferred to an SD card.

Answer (score 4):

After further research it seems that direct transfer from system to micro-SD is not possible and you have to re-download games.

See quote from official Nintendo site below:

> Software data cannot be moved from the console's system memory to the microSD card.
>
> If you'd like to store software data on the microSD card, you must first delete the data from the console's system memory. Then, open Nintendo eShop and redownload the data to the microSD card.

[Source](https://www.nintendo.com.au/help/switch-frequently-asked-questions)